# How to apply no background?

Tags: xfce, desktop-background, ubuntu-studio

Where is the option to apply no background on the desktop settings?
I'm using Ubuntu Studio (Xfce desktop).
On the desktop settings there is no option to apply no background or just a solid color.
Of course I can create an image with just a solid color and use it but that is not efficient.
The ideal would be:

- No Background image
- Just a solid color

Answer (score 9):

On the style drop-down menu, I just needed to choose "none".
[image]

Comment: Can't believe How reckless and stupid I am..

Comment: @cantiknonokmu you are not. It's extra unintuitive.

Comment: This is probably the most stupid UI detail in general. Anywhere. Now vote me down.